# Are Enochian sigils visible to humans?

Tags: supernatural

On Two occasions (when rescuing the reapers, and when they first find Crowley) we 'see' Enochian sigils glowing blue, once via entities that have been astrally projected, and once by an angel.

Are they normally visible to humans, or do the only show up on x-rays and via magic-vision?

Comment: The glow or the sigils themselves?

Comment: The Sigils. To my knowledge we always have a shot without them first, and then pan to angel-vision and they're there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on how they were made.  Enochian sigils, like the Devil's Traps, are all about the power of writing.  The "word" made into form/power.

Some examples:

- Castiel "carved" them into Sam and Dean's ribs.  I'm uncertain whether these were physical carvings, but [Castiel corrected Dean](http://supernatural.wikia.com/wiki/Enochian_sigil#Hide_From_Angels) from "brand" to "carve", which seems to imply a physical alteration.
- There's a lot of instances of the main characters drawing the sigils in their own blood, which would be visible to others.  For example:
  [image: Castiel drawing an Enochian sigil in his own blood]
- Sometimes they can be drawn in ways that regular humans cannot see, by way of an unknown substance and/or magic.  For example, how long do you think this *funeral home* would have lasted if these sigils were visible? [image: Sigils on a funeral home]

Comment: Note that Sam and Dean saw the sigils on their chest via an X-Ray, which strongly indicates that they physically altered the density of their bones and would be visible on the bones themselves.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield Thanks, I saw the picture of that on the wikia, but couldn't really make out what it was, and had forgotten about that entirely.  If they sigils were visible by x-ray, then at the very least, that confirms that they were "carved" onto the bone through some sort of physical means (density, carving as with a knife, something etched into the bone), but almost certainly not magic or with whatever was used on the funeral home.

Comment: The demons have shown themselves to be practical when convenient. Nothing should (in theory) discourage them from using black light paint.